# Simple ASP.net ToolTip (for FireFox)

Tags: asp.net, tooltip

I have an ImageButton in ASP.Net on my site, filled with the property ToolTop:

```
<asp:ImageButton CausesValidation="false" Enabled="false" ID="imgHelp" ImageUrl="Images/Icons/help.png" Width="15px" Height="15px"
                            runat="server" ToolTip="Die Referenz der Anfrage, z.B.: Bieter- oder Auktionsnummer"  />
```

But in FireFox the ToolTip isn't shown up.

Someone an Idea for which reasen OR know a good free to use ToolTip-UC?

---

This is the generated code:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$imgHelp" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_imgHelp" disabled="disabled" title="Die Referenz der Anfrage, z.B.: Bieter- oder Auktionsnummer" src="Images/Icons/help.png" style="height:15px;width:15px;border-width:0px;" />
```

---

Ok I see my problem, when the ImageButton is Enabled, the tooltip works, but the user can click on it (what I don't want). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is it won't work in Firefox because you have the control's enabled property set to false. If you set it to true does this fix the problem?

**Update**- this is by design in Firefox. If you want to get round this, you will have to use something like a JavaScript tooltip mechanism.

**Update 2:**

Use the asp:Image tag:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="the Id" 
   ToolTip="Die Referenz der Anfrage, z.B.: Bieter- oder Auktionsnummer"  
   ImageUrl="TheImage.jpg" 
   AlternateText="Some alt here" />
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but than it's clickable, what I don't want to have.

Comment: If you don't want it to be clickable why are you adding it as an ImageButton and not just a normal image?

Comment: In a normal Image I can't have the ToolTip!

Comment: @richeym- that's a good point. What's wrong with using <asp:Image /> or even <img> html tag?

Comment: Ok I found my fool: I tried to use the <img>-html-tag and not the Image ASP tag, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ASP.NET, but I'm sure looking at the generated HTML will tell you more on why it doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding "onclick=return(false);" so that clicking means nothing. Also change the css of the pointer to normal so it won't even appear as clickable.

Answer (score 0):

How to apply the css for
ToolTip="Die Referenz der Anfrage, z.B.: Bieter- oder Auktionsnummer"  in any control